# Modifying values directly using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible to modify elements of a collection, say List, LinkedList, etc using something like:

```
collection.Do ( action )
```

which does something like:

```
item.Value = 0
(for each item)
```

I know enumerators only give the value, not the reference, hence the question.

How would one do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
void ModifyEach<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, T> modifier)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < list.Count; n++)
        list[n] = modifier(list[n]);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> x = new List<int> { 1, 3, 7 };

x.ModifyEach(n => n + 1); // increment each item
```

Comment: Not unless you use IEnumerable.ElementAt(), because by default IEnumerable doesn't provide random access. You can't use foreach because that would modify the collection.

Comment: No, it can only work with a collection interface that allows you to modify the contents of the list at a specific position, which basically means IList or IDictionary.

Comment: @Andy, ElementAt is no use; what's needed is the ability to modify the collection, not random access (I'm only using the [int] indexer to allow modification).

Comment: Couldn't you just do x = x.Select(n => n + 1).ToList(); ?

Comment: @Cameron, That would create a new list rather than doing an in-place modification of the existing list.

Comment: @Luke: True, I wasn't sure if that made a difference to the original poster or not.

Answer (score 2):

If your collection contains reference types then you can modify its items in-place by using an extension method, similar to the `ForEach` method on `List<T>`.

This is possible because you're not actually trying to alter the `IEnumerable<T>` sequence: The collection contains references but you're only modifying the referenced objects, not the references themselves.

This technique won't work for collections of value types. In that case you would be trying to alter the read-only, `IEnumerable<T>` sequence, which isn't possible.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}

// ...

public class Example
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

// ...

Example[] examples =
    {
        new Example { Value = 1 }, new Example { Value = 2 },
        new Example { Value = 3 }, new Example { Value = 4 }
    };

examples.ForEach(x => x.Value *= 2);

// displays 2, 4, 6, 8
foreach (Example e in examples)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
}
```